# How to use a variable in the equalTo() in firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write code to delete a user from the database. Here is the code(the two methods I make use of to that) :

```js
goToDeleteUser(email)
  { console.log(email);
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user ?',
      buttons: [
         { 
           text: 'Delete',
           handler: function(email)  
           {
             console.log(email);
             this.deleteUser(email);
           }
         }
       ]
    });
    confirm.present();

  }
  
deleteUser(email)
  {  console.log(email);
     var userid;
     firebase.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("child_added",(snapshot)=>{
     userid=snapshot.val().uid}) ;
     console.log(userid);
     firebase.database().ref('users/userid').remove();
  }
```

The problems I am facing are :

1. The second 'console.log(email)' which is in the 'handler' of the 'buttons' isn't showing the correct output while the one immediately after 'goToDeleteUser(email)' is.

2.When I am using 'orderByChild', I need to pass the variable 'email' to the 'equalTo()' in it which it somehow is not accepting.

How to resolve these ? Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming conflict:

```
handler: function(email) <--- Here 
{
    console.log(email);
    this.deleteUser(email);
}
```

The handler passed back data about the inputs in your alert, which you have none. `email` has already been reserved by the function your alert sits in. Just remove the `email` parameter inside `handler` and that should fix everything.

```
goToDeleteUser(email)
{ 
    console.log(email);
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user ?',
        buttons: [
        { 
            text: 'Delete',
            handler: function()  <--- remove email has parameter
                {
                    console.log(email);
                    this.deleteUser(email);
                }
        }]
   });
   confirm.present();

}

deleteUser(email)
{  
    console.log(email);
    var userid;
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("child_added",(snapshot)=>{
    userid=snapshot.val().uid}) ;
    console.log(userid);
    firebase.database().ref('users/userid').remove();
}
```